# Bootrsap styling issue when executing PHP query

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, select

I'm having an issue styling a form when a selection option is in a php echo.
The select from doesn't display like the subject form, depsite the classes being the same.

```
echo '<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="">
    <h2> Add A Topic to Forum</h2>
    <div class="row>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
           <label class="sr-only" for="tsubject">Subject</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="topic_subject id="tsubject" placeholder="Subject"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <label class="sr-only" for="tcat">Category</label>'; 

            echo '<select class="form-control" name="topic_cat" id="tcat>';
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
                    }

                    echo '</select>'; 
                    echo '</div>';

    </div>
    </form>
</div>';
```

Comment: you forgot to put double quote on `id="tcat` , which should be `id="tcat"`

Comment: You need to `echo "</div></form></div>"` at the end. In general when asking a question, make sure to state what the output is and in how far that differs from your expectation. Since we do not know how the "subject form" looks like, we cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="">
    <h2> Add A Topic to Forum</h2>
    <div class="row>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
           <label class="sr-only" for="tsubject">Subject</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" name="topic_subject id="tsubject" placeholder="Subject"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <label class="sr-only" for="tcat">Category</label>'; 

            echo '<select class="form-control" name="topic_cat" id="tcat">';
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
                    }

                    echo '</select>'; 
                    echo '</div>';

 echo '</div>
    </form>
</div>';
```

put echo from the second last  `</div>` element

Comment: That isn't doing it

Comment: Can u pls Clearly explain  @andre

Comment: The first forum group class is perfect. Styles the way i want it.  For the select class the php works but the bootstrap styling isn't/ That input field is indented under the first one with no space.

Comment: u also missing  double quote on `id="tcat`